# gocql/gocql fails create new session: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql

I'm working on a api written with Go, that has a main goal that it should answer the request as fast as possible. I came up with using goroutines.

I test it with wrk with this command:

```
$ wrk -t1 -c200 -d1s http://127.0.0.1:8080    
// this passes
...
21efef3
21efef3
21efef3
21efef3
21efef3
21efef3
21efef3
...

$ wrk -t1 -c400 -d1s http://127.0.0.1:8080
// this test fails with this error returned in go terminal
...
21efef3
21efef3
21efef3
21efef3
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x6ada46]

goroutine 2325 [running]:
github.com/gocql/gocql.(*Session).Close(0x0)
/home/mda/.local/go/src/github.com/gocql/gocql/session.go:336 +0x26
panic(0x707f40, 0x8ed650)
/usr/lib/go-1.8/src/runtime/panic.go:489 +0x2cf
github.com/gocql/gocql.(*Session).Query(0x0, 0x777d4c, 0x34, 0xc428cfd190, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0)
/home/mda/.local/go/src/github.com/gocql/gocql/session.go:294 +0x26
main.getData()
/home/mda/code/api-go/main2.go:45 +0x1f6
created by main.main.func1
/home/mda/code/api-go/main2.go:18 +0x39
exit status 2

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Cassandra seems to work fine

```
$ cassandra-stress read n=200000 -pop seq=1..200000 -rate threads=200 -node 127.0.0.1

Results:
Op rate                   :   14,090 op/s  [READ: 14,090 op/s]
Partition rate            :   14,090 pk/s  [READ: 14,090 pk/s]
Row rate                  :   14,090 row/s [READ: 14,090 row/s]
Latency mean              :   14.1 ms [READ: 14.1 ms]
Latency median            :    9.7 ms [READ: 9.7 ms]
Latency 95th percentile   :   39.4 ms [READ: 39.4 ms]
Latency 99th percentile   :   72.1 ms [READ: 72.1 ms]
Latency 99.9th percentile :  218.1 ms [READ: 218.1 ms]
Latency max               :  346.8 ms [READ: 346.8 ms]
Total partitions          :    200,000 [READ: 200,000]
Total errors              :          0 [READ: 0]
Total GC count            : 14
Total GC memory           : 4.346 GiB
Total GC time             :    0.4 seconds
Avg GC time               :   31.9 ms
StdDev GC time            :    9.4 ms
Total operation time      : 00:00:14
```

This is a simplified version of my Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "github.com/buaazp/fasthttprouter"
    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp/reuseport"
    "github.com/gocql/gocql"
)

var cluster *gocql.ClusterConfig

func main() {
    router := fasthttprouter.New()

    router.GET("/", func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {

        // We need this goroutine
        go getData()
        fmt.Fprint(ctx, "Welcome to home!")
        ctx.Response.Header.ConnectionClose()
    })

    ln, err := reuseport.Listen("tcp4", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error in reuseport listener: %s", err)
    }

    if err = fasthttp.Serve(ln, router.Handler); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error in fasthttp Server: %s", err)
    }
}

func setup_cluster() {
    cluster = gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1:9042")

    cluster.Keyspace = "myKeySpace"
    cluster.Consistency = gocql.One
}

func getData() {
    if cluster == nil {
        setup_cluster()
    }
    session, _ := cluster.CreateSession()
    defer session.Close()

    var id string
    var value string

    if err := session.Query(`SELECT id, ads FROM product_ads 
        WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1`,
        "213").Consistency(gocql.One).Scan(&id, &value); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // ... do some stuff with id & value
    fmt.Println(value)

}
```

here is the process limits of my go code and cassandra, they have the same values set for different users:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             32768                32768                processes
Max open files            1000000              1000000              files
Max locked memory         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       31265                31265                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

what do you suggest? why Go fails to create new session?

Comment: 1) Why do you keep closing the session? 2) Have you tried upping the timeout by setting a higher timout value on the `gocql.ClusterConfig` (`cluster.Timeout`)? 3) `session, _ := cluser.CreateSession()` <-- _use_ the error value this returns to find out more. 4) Acutally: Why are you using the same `gocql.ClusterConfig` every time to create a new session? It's clear the session wasn't created, but because you don't check for errors, and just blindly `defer session.Close()` you end up calling `Close` on a `nil` pointer, resulting in a runtime panic

Comment: 4) gocql.ClusterConfig is just a struct that keeps my clusterconfig, why should i bother create it every time ( correct me if I misunderstood it) 3) the error returns just the same error i pasted in question. 2) yes 1) I can't get it. examples keep doing that. is it possible not to close it? interesting idea. thanks. i'll give it a try

Comment: 4) Missed the fact that `cluster` was a global, my mistake. 3) I don't see any gocql errors in your question, just a runtime panic. 2) That closes down that route then :P, 1) All gocql examples basically give you an overview of the flow, but you can keep a session open as long as you want to/need to. Of course, connections can (and will) be lost, make sure to check for `session` to be still valid/connected. If you lose the connection, then make sure to reconnect or gracefully exit

Comment: yes, that was not an error. it was just a break point for the app under pressure. but that situation could not be avoided, even with some retry functionality. anyways... your suggestion worked well. I created a global session and stopped closing it and boom, I got no panic error. And wrk couldn't break anything down. thanks for your advice. @EliasVanOotegem